# How to access files of subpackage from a file of the parent package?

Tags: python, import, module, package

```
E:.
└───Fruit
  ├───Apple
  │  ├───KashmiriApple.py
  │  └───__init__.py
  ├───Orange
  │  ├───ChennaiOrange.py
  │  └───__init__.py
  ├───main.py
  └───__init__.py
```

The contents of all **init**.py are empty.

The contents of KashmiriApple.py is:

```
def say_hi_apple():
    print("Kashmiri Apple says Hi!")
```

The contents of ChennaiOrange.py is:

```
def say_hi_orange():
    print("Chennai Orange says Hi!")
```

The contents of main.py is:

```
import Fruit.Orange.ChennaiOrange as CO

CO.say_hi_orange()
```

Executing the code of main.py gives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Fruit'

I don't want to use sys package to update the location of the package.

Now how can I import the subpackage's file in my main.py file?

I executed this in VS Code and it caused an error. But running in PyCharm does not give an error and runs succesfully.

Why does this happen and how can I resolve it?

I executed this in VS Code and it caused an error. But running in PyCharm does not give an error and runs succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

Your main.py exists at the same level that Fruit is.

Try this one:

> from Orange import ChennaiOrange as CO